# Unfortunately System UI has stopped After Installing Cordova App in Nougat

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-7.0-nougat, motorola

Recently I have installed my Android Application(hybrid app) in My Mobile which has the Latest OS version **Nougat**.

The Problem is After that my phone keeps Crashing. Everytime. With the Message **"System UI has Stopped"** Even I can't able to Uninstall that Particular App. The same Problem Happening for the Emulators too.

**Problems :**

- Can't able to Uninstall that Particular Application
- Cant Access settings for that particular App
- Even 3rd Part Uninstallers also Fails to Uninstall
- Phone Crash while clicking the Options Menu Button

This happens only with Nougat only. Lower versions it works Perfectly. Any help..?? Thanks in Advance

**App development Environment :** Cordova 6.5.0

**Added Plugins :**

- com.filfatstudios.spinnerdialog 1.0.2 "SpinnerDialog"
- cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console" cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6
  "Device"
- cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"
- cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"

**Test Device :** MotoG5 Plus (Nougat 7.0)

**Emulator :**  Nexus (Nougat 7.0)

Comment: Try uninstalling Google app updates

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the Solution.

Somewhat my app contains some Plugins that were not Supported in Nougat
So just Uninstalled the App by Using the following Command

**adb uninstall io.cordova.hellocordova**

here *io.cordova.hellocordova* is the Package name of that Application.

After the Uninstallations all problems get resolved and Saved My Phone :)